# Emberjs common router events

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to join common events to a route, and then extend the route as needed

Like this:

```
App.ScrollTopRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   
   renderTemplate: function() {
           console.log('Hi this works ?');
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
});
```

Then I extend the route:

```
App.TodoRoute = App.ScrollTopRoute.extend({   
  model: function(params) {
    return App.Todo.find(params.todo_id);
  }
});
```

The problem is the events inside ScrollTopRoute are not launch

So which is the best way to join common routines for routes?

Comment: edit my answer to include a demo for the `Mixin` part and how you might call the function defined in the `Mixin` from the route extending that `Mixin` have a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing DOM related operations which should go into the `didInsertElement` of a `view`.

So for your `window.scrollTo(0, 0)` to work it should be defined in such a hook, assuming you have a `todos` template than this should work.

```
App.TodosView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }
});
```

In the case you need common code to be executed in different classes one possible way is to create a [`Mixin`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Mixin.html) and mix it into the classes that need it.

For example:

```
App.CommonMixin = Ember.Mixin.create({
  myCommonFunction: function() {
    console.log('this works');
  }
});

App.ScrollTopRoute = Ember.Route.extend(App.CommonMixin, {
  ...
  // myCommonFunction is available here
});

App.AnotheScrollTopRoute = Ember.Route.extend(App.CommonMixin, {
  ...
  // myCommonFunction is available here
});
```

As for the Mixin, see here for a [simple demo](http://jsbin.com/uwofoj/2/edit).

Hope this answers your question, if not let me know so I can improve it further.